# Is it possible to preview remote desktop on php website?

Tags: php, rdp, vnc

Is it possible to view remote desktop connection on php website? Just preview, not interactive window. I know, how to connect to remote desktop using VNC but it opens it in a separate tab and you can control the window.

Comment: PHP really has nothing to do with the question, which is asking if there is "some software, that runs in a browser (and can be displayed in a particular site), that shows a non-interactive stream of a some desktop"? (And I'm quite sure there is: at the core this is no different than a live-streaming video.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is: No.

How this is typically done is by getting the server to generate screenshots and getting those images to be embedded in PHP so it gets displayed on the site.

If you fancy a live stream them you'd need some service that generates that feed in a way that PHP can then display it. This guy here did it for screen casting his online sessions:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYrjI_u3ka8

Basically using Google Hangouts to broadcast it into YouTube and embedding it in your page using:

https://github.com/kassius/youtube-live-embed

From the example:

```
require_once('EmbedYoutubeLiveStreaming.php'); // Use this if the class file from repo is in the same directory
$channelId = 'REPLACE_ME'; // This is the your CHANNEL ID
$api_key = 'REPLACE_ME'; // This is your google project API KEY with youtube api enabled
$YouTubeLive = new EmbedYoutubeLiveStreaming($channelId, $api_key);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: aha...! That's nice idea.